# Rails 3 Speed up Active Record Callbacks after_commit to send notifications using Private_pub

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using 3 callbacks after a post is created.

1) Post created

callback#1) `after_commit :do_notify, :on => :create`  for creating Notification

2) Notification created

callback#2) `after_commit :publish_to_all, :on => :create` for sending out messages/ to user using private_pub

It is taking more than a minute to complete the whole flow.

> Question#1: *Is the approach wrong?*
>
> Question#2: *Is there a method to send rest of callbacks to background
>   and complete it there?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yeah
2. do it async

there are also observers: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

and for the async task you could use: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs